# PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider equivalent in Jersey2

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-1.0

What is the equivalent of PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider in Jersey2?

I've tries to use AbstractBinder but it doesn't seem to work.
The Seesion I'm trying to inject is always null.

I tried to replace jersey-1 old code

```
public class UserSessionProvider extends PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider<Context, Session> {

  @Context HttpServletRequest request;

  public UserSessionProvider() {
    super(Session.class);
  }

  @Override
  public Injectable<Session> getInjectable(ComponentContext cc, Context context) {
    return new Injectable<Session>() {

      @Override
      public Session getValue() {
        Session session = SessionUtils.createSession(request);
        request.setAttribute(WebSessionConfig.s.servlet_attribute_name, session);
        return session;
      }
    };
  }
}
```

with jersey-2 new code, replacing PerRequestTypeInjectableProvider with AbstractBinder:

```
public class UserSessionProvider extends AbstractBinder {

  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserSessionProvider.class);

  @Context HttpServletRequest request;

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    bind(SessionResolver.class).to(Session.class);
  }

  public class SessionResolver implements InjectionResolver<Session> {

    @Override
    public Object resolve(Injectee injectee, ServiceHandle<?> root) {

      Session session = SessionUtils.createSession(request);
      request.setAttribute(WebSessionConfig.s.servlet_attribute_name, session);
      return session;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConstructorParameterIndicator() {
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMethodParameterIndicator() {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the package was not registered.